# How can I map .NET DateTime to database DateTime2 using Dapper to avoid "SqlDateTime overflow" exception?

Tags: c#, dapper

I'm converting our existing system from Entity Framework to Dapper. For various corporate reasons, we can't really change the database. Some of the tables have columns that are of type `DateTime2`.

Dapper converts any .NET `DateTime` to `DbType.DateTime`. This causes exception:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException HResult=0x80131930
> Message=SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Is there any way to map .NET `DateTime` to database `DateTime2` using Dapper?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dapper is litterally a [single file](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs) that you include into your code base. Just edit the file:

Replace (around line 300):

```
        typeMap[typeof(Guid)] = DbType.Guid;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTime)] = DbType.DateTime;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTimeOffset)] = DbType.DateTimeOffset;
        typeMap[typeof(byte[])] = DbType.Binary;
```

With:

```
        typeMap[typeof(Guid)] = DbType.Guid;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTime)] = DbType.DateTime2;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTimeOffset)] = DbType.DateTimeOffset;
        typeMap[typeof(byte[])] = DbType.Binary;
```

**Edit:**
There's also a nullable DateTime further down that block of mappings, around line 319:

```
        typeMap[typeof(DateTime?)] = DbType.DateTime;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTimeOffset?)] = DbType.DateTimeOffset;
```

To:

```
        typeMap[typeof(DateTime?)] = DbType.DateTime2;
        typeMap[typeof(DateTimeOffset?)] = DbType.DateTimeOffset;
```

Comment: What if some are DateTime and others are DateTime2?

Comment: @MetroSmurf Actually, I think sticking with DateTime2 is the best choice. DATETIME2 has an implicit conversion to DATETIME and vice versa in SQL Server. The only problem will be loss of precision on the time stamp, because the .Net DateTime is more precise than the SQL Server DATETIME. This has been a known issue for years, however, which is why it's recommended to use DATETIME2 in the first place.

Comment: I did try this. However, you cannot insert a DateTime2 into a DateTime in SQL. You get an error. Or to be more accurate, I guess that if you declare your command parameter as DateTime2, SQL will not allow you to insert it into DateTime (I'm not sure if SQLClient is blocking it or if it is SQL itself).

Comment: Oh, I just realised, when I tested this, the date I was testing with still had MinValue, which is why SQL did not allow it to go into DateTime. So I guess I was on the right track all along.

Comment: Heh, I just noticed your followup reply. If it works, it works; I'll leave my edit in place in case somebody else needs it.

Comment: " When dates are sent to SQL Server, they're sent as a string, " - pretty sure they would be going as binary dates

Comment: @MarcGravell you're right. I forgot that .Net `SqlCommand` objects will wrap the `CommandText` for a `Text` type command in an *RPC-style call* to `sp_executesql`, which will cause the parameters to be sent in TDS native formats rather than as raw text. I blame the fact that I've been doing text-only queries on node.js recently.

Comment: Editing libraries is an extremely poor idea. It makes upgrading much more difficult. Also, this is no longer true. It's now a binary.

Answer (score 63):

There's a much easier solution now in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26282604/2503659), but it is about `string`.

For `DateTime`:

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(DateTime), System.Data.DbType.DateTime2);
```

This must be applied *before* any database call like `INSERT`.

You can put it in your `Main` or `Startup` class, or any place that runs on `Startup` to configure data access. `SqlMapper` is a `static` class and changes apply to all calls.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions provided will map the types globally because the list of mappings is static.

To create a list of parameters for a single command a better approach is to use the `DynamicParameters` class.

```cs
var parameters = new DynamicParameters(template);
parameters.Add("@DateTimeParam", dateTimeValue, DbType.DateTime2);
    
await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
```

Where `template` can be any object (including the previous parameters used). The `template` properties are going to be merged with the added parameters.

Answer (score 1):

For Date and time data with time zone awareness.

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeMap(typeof(DateTime), System.Data.DbType.DateTimeOffset);
```

I do not know why when I tried to use Datetime2, I still kept losing the milliseconds.
This DateTimeOffset type is also Datetime2.

The date value range is from January 1,1 AD through December 31, 9999 AD. The time value range is 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.9999999 with an accuracy of 100 nanoseconds. Time zone value range is -14:00 through +14:00.